# How to make 'independent' computed observable of some observable (Knockout.js)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have three observables

```
viewModel.a = ko.observable(0);
viewModel.b = ko.observable(0);
viewModel.c = ko.observable(0);
```

and I need them all in computed observable

```
viewModel.co = ko.computed(function(){
    var a = this.a();
    return this.b() + this.c();
}, viewModel);
```

How to make `co` to update only if updates `b` or `c`?
http://jsfiddle.net/DgVCF/

Comment: Does "How to make co to update only if updates b or c?" mean that co should only return a value if b or c is changed?

Comment: @EricHerlitz, no co should be updated only if b or c is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `peek()` function to get `a`'s value without creating a dependency on it in your computed:

```
viewModel.co = ko.computed(function(){
    var a = this.a.peek();
    console.log(1);
    return this.b() + this.c();
}, viewModel);
```

See also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#controlling_dependencies_using_peek).

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3VaZ2/).

Comment: how does this solve op's problem? "co should be updated only if b or c is changed"

Comment: @EricHerlitz this is exactly why the `peek()` exists, getting an observable value without creating "dependcenies". So `co` will be updated only when b or c changes. Have you checked my fiddle and read the linked section of the documentation?

Comment: it really solves) I probably confused you with return b + c, but this is exactly what I need)

Answer (score 0):

Seems more as a job for subscribing

```
var viewModel = {};

viewModel.a = ko.observable(0);
viewModel.b = ko.observable(0);
viewModel.c = ko.observable(0);

viewModel.co = ko.observable(0);

viewModel.b.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    viewModel.co(parseInt(viewModel.b()) + parseInt(viewModel.c()));
});

viewModel.c.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    viewModel.co(parseInt(viewModel.b()) + parseInt(viewModel.c()));
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Isn't it a litle bit too complicated regarding the @Nemesv's answer ?

Comment: Your code - although works for this example case- but unnecessarily duplicates all the logic instead of using the `ko.computed` and the built in `peek` functionality. What if OP's computed is way more complicated and it depends on more than two other properties?

Comment: @nemesv, true but what if there was other properties as d, e, f, g? Would you peek them as well?